# docs.getSettings returns "Insufficient permissions"?

Tags: scribd

Just started exploring the API.

I'm trying to get some documents' metadata via the following api call to:

```
api.scribd.com/api?method=docs.getSettings&doc_id=<dociId>&api_key=<apiKey>
```

It works fine for my documents, but for documents I do not own, I get a "Insufficient permissions" error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like docs.getSettings can only be used by owners. The [platform API reference](http://www.scribd.com/developers/platform/api) from Scribd for  [docs.getSettings](http://www.scribd.com/developers/platform/api/docs_getsettings) says: "The current user must have uploaded this document, or will cause an access denied error.". See also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/scribd-platform-developers/P8Tusx0Y_cY/18dd4OZmhTAJ) on Google groups.